# How to fix deployment error QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, gae-quotas

I can't deploy my app, and I don't know how to fix it. I don't have any scaling configurations in my `app.yaml`, so I assume I'm under automatic scaling stuff. I'm using the flex env.

I only have two instances of the app right now and only three versions of it. So I'm not over any version limit.

I deployed once yesterday and it worked fine. when I changed some code and went to deploy again this happened. (I didn't save my changes to a different branch, so I don't know if it's just my code or some config I need to change in the console).

I'm not seeing anything related to my code in the build logs. The build seems like it succeeds 'cause it's green in the logs and says complete. Then it fails to update and gives me this quota error I can't find anything about in any docs.

Does this have anything to do with me getting two new domain names after the first deployment? (why would that matter?)

Here's the error:

```
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                           
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/blah/regions/us-east1/operations/2c43cd11-2628-430b-9593-2020202020 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-05-15T12:29:00.026Z67978.jc.2: Deployment Manager operation blah/operation-1589545740347-5a5aef53528c6-475fc7be-b67854 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/abc-default-12300515t082612/resources/abc-default-12300515t082612"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"usageLimits\",\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'abc-default-12300515t082612\'. Limit: 8.0\",\"reason\":\"limitExceeded\"}],\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'abc-default-20200515t0820000\'. Limit: 8.0\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/blah/regions/us-east1/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
```

dumb dumb dumb dumb dumb ;)

Comment: @Edgardo I have no clue I'm still trying to figure it out., and what library?

Comment: @blahblah I having the same issue, I've been trying to solve this issue for the pasted 3 days and no luck. M wondering if you managed to fix it and How???

Comment: @O.Moloi google said they're looking into it, but others that have run into this seem to have bypassed this issue by setting max_num_instances to 7. Here's a link:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157161938#comment2 .  I know waiting for engineers to come up with a soln could take weeks or moths so for the time being I just deployed under app engine standard  instead and it works just fine.

Comment: @blahblah Thanks, will have a look at the link and try their recommendations