# Unable to deploy Custom Runtime AppEngine in GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deployment

I tried to deploy a Custom Runtime Application in GCP, but it failed during the deployment with the following error message.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/custom-runtime-app/regions/asia-south1/operations/5f33c87e-b5fc-4896-ad3a-745f014b2d19 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2023-08-10T08:04:17.559Z1108.pt.1: Deployment Manager operation custom-runtime-app/operation-1691654658441-6028d0affbfd9-b08c5121-7ca0a212 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20230810t133154/resources/aef-default-20230810t133154"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"INTERNAL_ERROR\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":\"INTERNAL_ERROR\"}"
]
```

Can someone explain, what do I miss?

my app.yaml is

```
runtime : custom
env : flex
```

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM python
WORKDIR ./
ADD ./main.py ./
CMD [ "python","./main.py" ]
```

Comment: To know more about the error try running this command `--verbosity=debug`.Also try  setting the max\_num\_instances check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63005298/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819525/how-to-fix-deployment-error-quota-for-instances)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya thanks for the suggestion. it worked. To deploy a custom runtime application the app.yaml should have the following keys:

`runtime: custom
env: flex
automatic_scaling : 
  min_num_instances : 1
  max_num_instances : 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a custom runtime application, you can configure automatic scaling by specifying the number of instances in `automatic_scaling` section to your `app.yaml`

Your app.yaml file would something similar to:

Using automatic scaling

```
runtime : custom
env : flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
```